# Should an anchor be the parent or child of a heading element?

Tags: html

Let's say I want to display some links to a company's **About Us**, **Jobs** and **Blog** pages. And I decide to contain each link in level four heading elements:

```html
  <h4>About Us</h4>
  <h4>Jobs</h4>
  <h4>Blog</h4>
```

I would then also need to use `<a>` elements to create the links. So, should the headings contain the anchors? Or the other way round? Does it even matter?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are talking about? You use `id="..."` to create an anchor and uses `http://www.example.org/#someId` to jump to that anchor with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use heading element inside anchor element and also can use anchor element inside heading element.

```html
<a href="#"><h4>About Us</h4></a>
<a href="#"><h4>Jobs</h4></a>
<a href="#"><h4>Blog</h4></a>
```